# Chip vs printed circuit board

Tags: pcb, asic

What is the difference between a chip, wafer, and PCB? Are PCB individual components cut out from bigger wafers?

Comment: -1. If you know all these terms, why didn't you use wikipedia to get **general** information, then ask **specific** questions here?

Comment: A wafer goes into a chip, a chip goes on a PCB (printed circuit board).

Comment: It's only broad because there's a notable lack of understanding I think. That said, even bare minimum research would have provided sufficient info to OP to make the question more specific.

Answer (score 4):

A wafer is a disk made of silicon (mainly) containing many chips.

A wafer is sawn to separate it into individual dies

A die is the same as a chip or integrated circuit.

A chip is then placed in a housing, a small black box with metal pins.

A PCB or Printed Card Board by itself has nothing to do with chips.
There were PCBs already before chips existed.

A PCB is a fiberglass plate with copper traces to connect all the components together.

Comment: +1 for being to the point. It's always been clear to me that ICs and PCBs serve different purposes. But I did not know they are made differently. Why is that so? Can't PCBs be manufactured like a chip? I mean, they have conductive traces and non-conductive to substrates, similar to ICs, no?

Comment: A PCB is more like a "placeholer" for the components. An IC (integrated circuit) is much more than that. In theory you could make a silicon wafer and use it as a PCB but that would be overkill and **very** expensive. Also, silicon is very brittle (like glass), PCB material is much stronger and cheaper.

Comment: PCBs are made in a somewhat similar way in that the process of etching the copper traces is similar to how the copper or aluminium traces (connections) are etched on a chip. But the scale is entirely different. On a chip a 0.1 mm trace is already very wide. On a PCB it's about the minimum you can make reliably. In ICs there are a lot more components that van be made, namely active components like diodes and transistors. Passive components like resistors, capacitors and inductors can be made both on chip and on a PCB but the range of values is limited though (small values only).

Comment: Makes sense. This actually addressed the question I had posted in the comment to the other answer.

Comment: To clarify your last sentence, the range of values is limited on an IC (not PCB), right? If I remember from my undergraduate days, inductors are hard to corporate in an IC design, but capacitances are easier to introduce.

Comment: Also on a PCB, since usually on a PCB the traces are made of copper (which is highly conductive) you cannot (easily) make high value resistors without them becoming extremely large. And a simple SMD resistor of any value costs 1 cent. For inductors and capacitors it is the same, small values only. PCB capacitors and inductors are mainly used in high frequency RF designs, microwave circuits etc, for example, see this microwave filter on a PCB: http://www.microwavejournal.com/ext/resources/images/Figures/2012/June/6M33F4x250.jpg  Note that "microwave" here means high frequency signals.

Answer (score 3):

A wafer is the round plate of silicon that integrated circuits (ICs) are created on (using various chemical methods). Generally, multiple ICs are created on a single wafer. The wafer is cut to separate the individual ICs. Sometimes, there are called chips. In practice however, the work chip can refer to either the 'bare' IC cut from the wafer, or the packaged IC (encased in plastic with wires bonded to external terminals).

A PCB is a different thing altogether. It is the 'printed circuit board' that all components of an electronic apparatus are mounted on. It provides that electrical connections between the components using (mostly) copper traces and pads that the electronic components (chips, resistors, etc.) can be soldered into/onto.

In some cases, the 'bare IC' is mounted directly on the PCB and covered with a blob of epoxy in stead of being encased in packaging first - this is called a 'chip on board' construction and is often seen in mass produced, cheap products like calculators, remote controls etc.

A PCB is an entirely different thing from a silicon wafer. The PCB is used to interconnect various electrical and electronic components and mount them in some sort of housing.
A silicon waver and the integrated circuits created from them are very specific semiconductor devices (primarily transistors) that serve a very specific purpose. They are designed by experts who are able to figure out the physics required to make the silicon semiconductors behave they way they have to by 'doping' certain areas on the wafer positively or negatively (creating N and P material), adding various structure by layering chemicals (aluminum etc.) and etching those layers.

I suggest you Google 'introduction to semiconductors' - this will provide you with a plethora of information on silicon wavers and what's made using them. You'll then understand that PCBs and Silicon Wavers are different things entirely - one cannot replace all (most) functions of the other.

Comment: +1. Similar to what I asked FakeMoustache in the comment, why do PCBs have different material and are made differently than chips?

Comment: RJR I see you've updated your answer. I know this may be going off on a tangent from OP's original question, but I can't help but think IC is much more complicated than a PCB, and so we should be able to make an IC that has the same function as a PCB. I'm no process engineer, but can't we just use silicon dioxide instead of fiberglass as the insulator? The conductive traces for the PCB can then be deposited accordingly using a metal layer. It's surely an overkill, but it can be done, can it not?

Comment: Everything can be done - at a price. But it's generally not worth it. Simple question - how are you going to power your chip, connect it to the devices peripherals (buttons, displays, etc.) and mount it in your case? You can't solder wires to a wafer, it's light sensitive so requires packaging, etc.